# how to write a regex to match a "\n" which is not followed another "\n"?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace "\n" with ""(empty string) only when "\n" is not followed by another "\n".

```
var text  = "abcdefg
             abcdefg

             1234556
             1234556

             ABCDEFG
             ABCDEFG";
```

So, if I have a string as the above, I want to make it like this after replacing "\n"s.

```
"abcdefgabcdefg

 12345561234556

 ABCDEFGABCDEFG";
```

But, I can't find out how to write a regex to match a "\n" that is not followed another "\n".

These are what I tried, but these match both "\n" and "\n\n".

```
var pattern1 = new RegExp("\\n{1}");
var pattern2 = new RegExp("\\n(?!\\n)");
```

Could anyone please help me to write a regex in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match the following:

`[^\\n](\\n)[^\\n]`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/eP9xD1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/([^\n])\n([^\n])/g` and replace it with `\1\2`.

**Usage**:

```
> str = 'abcdefg\nabcdefg\n\n1234556\n1234556\n\nABCDEFG\nABCDEFG';
> str.replace(/([^\n])\n([^\n])/g, '\1\2');
  "abcdefbcdefg

  123455234556

  ABCDEFBCDEFG"
```

[**REGEX DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/cT1nM2)

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WWQ99/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match `\n` which aren't followed by another `\n`:

```
\n(?!\n)
```